# Diameter of the moon from the diameter seen in the telescope

Tags: telescope, telescope-lens

I'm reading a chapter on convex lenses and it has this diagram:
[image]

The chapter explains that triangles ABC and ADE are similar. Thus, ratio of CB to DE is equal to the ratio of BA to AD.
Does this mean that

- if I look at the moon in the telescope that is 1 m long,
- and the moon appears to be (I will make up a number) 1 cm in diameter,
- knowing that the distance between moon and Earth is 384,000 km,

I can conclude that the moon is 3,840,000 m in diameter?

This is coming from `384,000 km / 1 m = X / 1 cm` or, when converted to meters, `384,000,000 / 1 = X / 0.01`

Comment: Great question, and in this case you can replace the lens concept with a [pinhole camera model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model) and obtain the exact same result. As far as I can tell your thinking is correct, but my coffee hasn't kicked in so let's see what others say. *Welcome to Astronomy!*

Comment: Okay, you said the moon is 3 840 000 m in diameter, or 3 840 km. It's off by ~400 km. Not bad.

Answer (score 1):

A telescope wouldn't have a single lens, I'm sure you know. If you were to use the setup in your diagram, focusing the image of the moon on a flat surface, you could find its diameter with the method provided. The distances f in the diagram are the focal length of the lens, where a very distant object will be in sharp focus, and that's where you'd end up placing the flat surface.